# Crear un diccionario en base a un dataframe en Python

Tags: python, pandas, diccionarios

Resulta que tengo un dataframe sobre el coronavirus el cual he agrupado por países mediante la función groupby de pandas para tener los casos en cada uno de ellos. Este dataframe agrupado tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
             5/22/20     5/23/20    5/24/20  ...

Country
Afghanistan     9219       10001    10585  ...
Albania          981         989      998  ...
Algeria         7918        8113     8306  ...
Andorra          762         762      762  ...
Angola            60          61       69  ...
....
```

Se puede ver que las cabeceras de las columnas son las fechas y las filas contienen cada uno de los casos de coronavirus (matizar que en el dataframe original los datos vienen organizados así y no he realizado cambios, solamente he hecho una agrupación).

Entonces, lo que me gustaría conseguir es un diccionario que tuviese el siguiente formato:

```
{
"Afghanistan": {"fecha": [5/22/20, 5/23/20, 5/24/20, ...], "casos": [9219, 10001, 10585...],
"Albania": {"fecha": [5/22/20, 5/23/20, 5/24/20, ...], "casos": [981, 989, 998,...],
...
}
```

He intentado hacer el diccionario mediante la función de pandas `to_dict()`, pero los outputs no son los deseados. Entiendo que para que en el diccionario salgan los campos "fecha" y "casos", lo primero sería crearlos en el dataframe para luego aplicar `to_dict()` sobre este, pero cómo las fechas están en las cabeceras de cada columna del dataframe y los casos son los datos de cada una de las filas, no sé muy bien cómo podría crear estos dos nuevos campos.

Muestro el output que he obtenido mediante la función `to_dict` y que es el que más se acercaría al diccionario buscado

```
# En el dataframe agrupado sumo por grupos (que son los países), y lo transformo en diccionario a través del índice:

grouped.sum().to_dict('index')

Out:
{'Afghanistan': {'1/22/20': 0,
  '1/23/20': 0,
  '1/24/20': 0,
  '1/25/20': 0,
  '1/26/20': 0,
  '1/27/20': 0,
  '1/28/20': 0,
  '1/29/20': 0,
  '1/30/20': 0,
  '1/31/20': 0,
  '2/1/20': 0,
  '2/2/20': 0,
  '2/3/20': 0,
  '2/4/20': 0,
  '2/5/20': 0,
  '2/6/20': 0,
  '2/7/20': 0,
   ....
```

El anterior diccionario sería el que más se parecería al que busco, pero como no he creado los campos "fecha" y "casos" no me aparece como me gustaría, y el tema es que no sé cómo podría crear dichos campos debido a la estructura del dataframe.

## Actualizo:

He conseguido distribuir los datos para tener dos columnas llamadas "fecha" y "casos" gracias a la función `melt` de pandas, la cual apliqué sobre el dataframe original:

```
melt_cov = covid19.melt(id_vars=["Country/Region"], 
        var_name="fecha", 
        value_name="casos")

melt_cov

Out:
      Country/Region    fecha   casos
0        Afghanistan    1/22/20 0
1            Albania    1/22/20 0
2            Algeria    1/22/20 0
3            Andorra    1/22/20 0
4             Angola    1/22/20 0
... ... ... ... ...
35889         Vietnam   5/31/20 328
```

Sin embargo, al agrupar por país y tratar de hacer el diccionario no obtengo el que quiero:

```
melt_cov.groupby(["Country/Region", "fecha"]).sum().to_dict('index')

Out:
{('Afghanistan', '1/22/20'): {'casos': 0},
 ('Afghanistan', '1/23/20'): {'casos': 0},
 ('Afghanistan', '1/24/20'): {'casos': 0},
 ('Afghanistan', '1/25/20'): {'casos': 0},
 ('Afghanistan', '1/26/20'): {'casos': 0},
....


melt_cov.groupby(["Country/Region", "fecha"]).sum().to_dict('list')

Out:
{'casos': [0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
...
```

Comment: Hola. Añade, por favor, un ejemplo con lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: @Adrián vale, hecho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy un experto trabajando con el módulo `pandas` pero intentaré darte una solución aunque no sea la más óptima (quizá):

Voy a intentar simular parte del dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Seteamos los datos (como el ejemplo que tienes)
data = [
    [9219, 10001, 10585],
    [981, 989, 998],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    # Los indices que serian los paises:
    index = ['Algeria', 'Andorra'],
    # Las columnas que serian las fechas
    columns = ['5/22/20', '5/23/20', '5/24/20'],
)
# El nombre como indice del dataframe:
df.index.name = 'Countries'
```

El contenido del dataframe (`df`):

```
           5/22/20  5/23/20  5/24/20
Countries                           
Algeria       9219    10001    10585
Andorra        981      989      998
```

Ahora:

- No entiendo exactamente el porqué de insertar las fechas en una lista y repetirla por cada país. Si tienes 100 países repetirás las mismas fechas 100 veces. Aún así, podrías almacenarlo en una lista de la siguiente manera:

```
dates = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

- Resto de código explicado entre comentarios:

```
# Creamos la variable como diccionario
result = dict()

# Por cada una de las columnas del dataframe
for column in df:
    # Accedemos a los datos del indice, es decir, pais y el valor de la columna iterando por cada uno de los items:
    for country, row_value in df[column].iteritems():
        # Si no existe la key country en el diccionario lo creamos
        if not country in result:
            result[country] = {}
        # Si no existe la key casos lo creamos
        if not "casos" in result[country]:
            result[country]["casos"] = []
        # Si no existe la key fecha lo creamos
        if not "fecha" in result[country]:
            result[country]["fecha"] = dates
        # Anadimos a la lista de casos los elemento del resto de columnas
        result[country]["casos"].append(row_value)
```

- Código total:

```
import pandas as pd

# Seteamos los datos (como el ejemplo que tienes)
data = [
    [9219, 10001, 10585],
    [981, 989, 998],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    # Los indices que serian los paises:
    index = ['Algeria', 'Andorra'],
    # Las columnas que serian las fechas
    columns = ['5/22/20', '5/23/20', '5/24/20'],
)
# El nombre como indice del dataframe:
df.index.name = 'Countries'

dates = df.columns.values.tolist()

# Creamos la variable como diccionario
result = dict()

# Por cada una de las columnas del dataframe
for column in df:
    # Accedemos a los datos del indice, es decir, pais y el valor de la columna iterando por cada uno de los items:
    for country, row_value in df[column].iteritems():
        # Si no existe la key country en el diccionario lo creamos
        if not country in result:
            result[country] = {}
        # Si no existe la key casos lo creamos
        if not "casos" in result[country]:
            result[country]["casos"] = []
        # Si no existe la key fecha lo creamos
        if not "fecha" in result[country]:
            result[country]["fecha"] = dates
        # Anadimos a la lista de casos los elemento del resto de columnas
        result[country]["casos"].append(row_value)

print(result)
```

- Resultado:

```
{'Algeria': {'casos': [9219, 10001, 10585], 'fecha': ['5/22/20', '5/23/20', '5/24/20']}, 'Andorra': {'casos': [981, 989, 998], 'fecha': ['5/22/20', '5/23/20', '5/24/20']}}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrián! :) La verdad es que estaba ofuscado intentando buscar la manera de crear el diccionario mediante la función `to_dict` de pandas y no me centré en hacer el diccionario tal y como tú has comentado. Es por eso por lo que estaba usando funciones como `melt` que quizás me dificultaban la tarea en vez de simplificarla. En fin, gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No te preocupes. Lamento no darte una respuesta más optimizada pero no controlo a fondo el módulo. Me alegra mucho haber sido de ayuda.